# Does Cassandra 3.0 run on Apple's M1 Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, cassandra, apple-m1, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to start apache-cassandra-3.0.15 in MacBook Pro with M1 chip and the build fails to start.
When i try to run cassandra.sh the following logs were found.

```
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset(Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset(Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize(Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents()Z
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop()V
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition()V
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush(I)V
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow()V
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow(JI)V
CompileCommand: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly(I)J
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds(JJ)V
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds(JJ)V
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary(Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan(Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo(Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo(Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompileCommand: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt(JI)[B
```

Please help me run cassandra in my development setup

Answer (score 3):

[Support for the ARM64 architecture](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.3/CHANGES.txt#L192) was added in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16384](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16384), [CASSANDRA-16392](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16392)). Apple's M1 chip runs on ARM64.

There are third-party components such as Netty in Cassandra 3.0 which does not support ARM64 so you won't be able to run older versions of Cassandra on M1 Macs. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** I've been informed by owners of Apple M1 Macs that they've had success with running older versions of Cassandra with [Apple Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT211861) installed. I'm not able to confirm this workaround since I don't have access to a M1 device so YMMV. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I will check this out.

Comment: is there a way for you to find me the workaround? It would be of huge help.